# How do I dodge the Cyclops snakes?

Tags: journey

So I'm at the part of the game where you start seeing the giant flying stone cyclops snakes with searchlights. I've been almost totally unable to dodge them, and they eat my scarf when they hit me.

What can I do to get past these unscathed? I'm having particular trouble in the snowy area, where I don't have any jump power and can't move very fast.

Comment: looked this game up it is very peculiar.

Comment: If you avoid their searchlight, they won't come after you. Otherwise your best bet is to flee as fast as you can (once you see one).

Comment: @Krazer is it actually possible to flee once they've "spotted" you?

Comment: @BenBrocka You can distract them while your companion flees. In certain parts (e.g. slope in the tunnels), if you move fast enough, they won't be able to catch you. I tend to hide and look overhead to make sure it's safe before I move on...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only winning move is not to play. Watch their patrols and hug the walls where their searchlights don't go as often. Once you get spotted by the search light, they will likely catch you unless you're in the last section where you're surfing down the middle as fast as possible. It is possible to get through it without losing the part of your scarf, but it's mostly stealth.

In the snowy area, you should utilize cover and only move out from under cover when no snakes are approaching.

Answer (score 1):

**Follow the left wall tightly**. All speedruns follow the left wall. (I have tried the right wall and middle, and they're much more perilous.) There are two main choke points: Underground's slide, and towards the end of Snow after the second glyph. In these parts, wait for the searchlight to make its rounds before forging forward. If you don't know the area, approach cautiously.

It's nigh impossible to dodge their attacks, but I've found that you can outfly them once they charge if you have the white robe and get enough air.